# JQuery - cannot wire up the change event

Tags: jquery

In my MVC application I have a form and I make 2 asynchronous AJAX calls, 1 to get a new page of data, the other to display the results of a search.
The intial load of the form prior to these calls is fine. I want to colour bar my rows, and this works;

```
$("#tblePagedList").on("change", styleRows);

function styleRows() {
    $("#tblePagedList tr:even").addClass("row1");
    $("#tblePagedList tr:odd").addClass("row2");
}
```

However these styles are not applied after I navigate to a new page or I make a search. My attempts to wire up a change event fail;

ie

```
$("#tblePagedList").on("change", styleRows);
```

or

```
$("#tblePagedList").change(styleRows);
```

My table looks like;

```
<table id="tblePagedList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Company
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
            <th style="width:100px;">
                Telephone
            </th>
            <th style="width:100px;">
                Contact
            </th>
            <th style="width:100px;">
                Trade
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tblePagedListBody"></tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Company
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.AddressLine
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Telephone
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Contact
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.TradeName
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "DetailsSubcontractor", new { id = item.CompanyId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Why not pure CSS? `#tblePagedList tr:nth-child(even) {/*style definition*/}` http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Answer (score 2):

[On Change event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) is triggered when input's value changes, not when DOM is altered.  If you need an event, I'd register a custom one, let's call it update:

```
`$("#tblePagedList").on("update", handler)`
```

and trigger it manually when AJAX call succeeds:

```
`$("#tblePagedList").trigger("update")`
```

But I'm not sure if you really need events. Perhaps calling `styleRows` in AJAX callback is enough?

And if you really like idea of events, consider switching to BackboneJS.  You could store fetched data in collection, hook to collection update event and render table on that event.

BTW Two subsequent `styleRows` calls may give wrong results, remove old classes:

```
function styleRows() {
    $("#tblePagedList tr:even").removeClass("row1 row2").addClass("row1");
    $("#tblePagedList tr:odd").removeClass("row1 row2").addClass("row2");
}
```

Comment: I have not tried backbone yet, I would love to learn it but it is on a long to do list. Maybe I will look at a pluralsight course over Christmas. Both your other solutions executed the styleRows function, but the styles did not persist into the output page. The CSS solution did work (see the comment under the question) and of course simple is best. However I learnt something from your answer as well, so I give an up tick.

Comment: @arame3333: Perhaps I misunderstood your question, but glad to help!  CSS solution by Yury Tarabanko is definitely best as long as it matches your browser requirements, however having not coloured rows in old IEs is not too bad.